# MySql: Select max value of per group with corresponding id of value

Tags: mysql

From my table, I want to select max likes in each user_id group with corresponding cat_id.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS likes;
CREATE TABLE likes
(
  user_id int,
  likes int,
  cat_id int
);

insert into likes(user_id, likes, cat_id) values
(2, 5, 56), 
(2,6,61), 
(2,7,70), 
(3,10,56), 
(3,11,61),
(3,9,70),
(4,14,56),
(4,15,61),
(4,16,70);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/51869/1

The **expected result**:

```
  user_id   max(likes)  cat_id
       2          7        70
       3         11        61
       4         16        70
```

But in the editor result is different. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is your expected result? Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza   the expected result is shown in question

Comment: Ok, I tought tha was current result... if you read the links you should always include both in your question. current and desire output. So we dont waste time trying the same thing.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza thanks, will keep that in mind next time

Comment: You asked the same question twice, see my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35625612/number-of-users-who-liked-the-most-objects-in-one-category/35627859#35627859

Comment: @sba I flagged that question for delete because it's badly presented, very confusing and too much code. This is smaller and simpler version

Comment: @sba I think is a much precise question. User, have you check my answeer? I include the sqlFiddle

Comment: Ah yes you simplified the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d9018/2)**

```
SELECT  likes.user_id, likes.likes, cat_id 
FROM likes
JOIN (
       Select user_id, max(likes) mlike
       from likes 
       group by user_id) T
    on likes.user_id = T.user_id
   and likes.likes = T.mlike
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| user_id | likes | cat_id |
|---------|-------|--------|
|       2 |     7 |     70 |
|       3 |    11 |     61 |
|       4 |    16 |     70 |
```

Comment: This query is relying on an implementation detail (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html). MySQL does not promise to read non-aggregated fields from the same row the aggregate selects. I assume that MAX() reads only one record if it's indexed so you're pretty safe there.

Comment: @sba are you sure? I know mysql isnt ANSI regarding group by. but there is only one field `user_id` and im grouping by that fields. So there isnt any non-aggregated field here

Comment: Sorry I misread. Indeed that way you avoid the issue altogether, nice solution!

Comment: Now I understand why I was confused about this query. The outer query allows duplicate rows per user.  This happens when two categories share the same like-count. The outer query needs grouping by `user_id` as well. Assuming we can pick any `cat_id` when there is a tie that field can be MAX'd or MIN'd according to taste so the fix is straightforward.

Comment: @sba Im not sure if you still saying this is wrong or you asking me to help understand the query. Anyway, if you see a case where query doesnt work you can update the SqlFiddle to support your comment and I will take a look